# pgsql cte with multiple references only running once

Tags: postgresql

Just wondering, is it the case in pgsql cte's that a temp table is created and the cte is not re-executed for each time it's joined in the query?  Below is the pgsql and sql server versions of the same query, sql server takes 6 seconds, pgsql only takes 3.  Is this a fluke or will it always be the case?

pgsql:

```
with a as(select pg_sleep(3), 1 b)
select 1 
from a t1
join a t2 on t1.b=t2.b
```

sql server:

```
with a as(SELECT b FROM 
  OPENQUERY([anylinkedserver],'WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:03'';select 1 b;'))
select 1 
from a t1
join a t2 on t1.b=t2.b
```

Comment: I think that `OPENQUERY` in SQL Server affects the optimizer. I'd use `SET STATISTICS IO` and query plan to check whether `CTE` is executed twice.

Comment: Sql server always executes the query multiple times if referenced more than once, that much I know for sure.  I'm asking how pgsql acts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus, expensive
>   calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
>   WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible application is to
>   prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions with side-effects.

Source: [The fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: i glazed over once i hit the recursive header on that page, they should really put that tidbit under a bold header, since it has nothing to do with the recursion section.  thanks!

Comment: I won't argue with you.